# Setting multiple sets of environment variables in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5

***Edit:** This question orignally applied to testing, but essentially I'd like to know if it's possible to have more than one .env file that can define multiple sets of environment variables; much like how L4 did it with `env.local.php`, `env.testing.php` etc*

---

I'm using Laravel 5 and developing on homestead box.

I have my .env file populated with my local environment variables (mysql database etc).

I wish to use an sqlite database for testing so I added some variables to `phpunit.xml` so it looks like this:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="DB_DRIVER" value="sqlite" />
    <env name="DB_PATH" value="database.sqlite" />
</php>
```

All the appropriate environment variables are referenced in the config files e.g. `env('DB_DRIVER')`.

Yet, when I try to migrate the database using `php artisan migrate --env=testing` I get "nothing to migrate" suggesting Laravel is trying to migrate my local (mysql) database (which is already migrated).

I decided to explore further via tinker, so I ran `php artisan tinker --env=testing`. Within tinker I ran `app()->environment();` which returned "testing". So far so good!

Next I echoed out the env variables via `$_ENV`, and it returned my **local** environment variables, despite the environment being set to testing.

Why is this? It seems Laravel is ignoring the phpunit.xml env variables and just using the .env file regardless...

**Edit**

It seems laravel only uses the phpunit.xml file if run via phpunit itself, even if the environment is set to testing separately.

If anyone knows how to set multiple environments in L5 I'm appreciate it as the L4 way of just making a `.env.testing` file doesn't work.

Comment: The configuration values in your **phpunit.xml** file will only be used by PHPUnit. Any Artisan commands will use what’s in your **.env** file.

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround for the original question, just the *testing* environment case, is to call `$this->artisan('migrate');` from `tests/TestCase.php` class, so it will get the database configuration values defined in `phpunit.xml` and perform the migration.

Comment: Indeed that looks like the best solution. That's actually what I ended up doing.

Answer (score -2):

Define your enviroment variables in you .env file.
For example:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Then you can access these variable using

```
env('DB_HOST')
```

Comment: The question is regarding testing-specific environment variables. Line 2 of the question states that there is a `.env` file present.